# Eclipse IDE Delete Key Woes

Tags: eclipse, ide, key

I have done some exhaustive searching and I have been unable to find any direction. Any time I try to type delete to delete some proceeding text in the IDE, or even try to paste something I get a menu that pops up in the lower right corner of the page. I'm not sure how it got turned on, or how to turn it off. It makes deleting text and copy and pasting very laborious. Here is an example of what eclipse looks like when I hit the delete key...

[image: screenshot]

Again, note the small menu that appears in the lower right corner. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: lol, brilliant. I hate eclipse. try intellij you won't regret it, or netbeans.

Comment: I'd use netbeans, except I have to use eclipse for a class.

Comment: This also applies for undo (Ctrl+Z)

Answer (score 1):

It is for sure a plugin that you have installed, something that has to do with the clipboard ... 
It could be [MoreClipboard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/moreclipboard/), try to remove the plugin, once removed that popup should disappear .